# Python variable not working as expected

Tags: python, variables, python-3.3

I set damage to 3 at the top but when I type damage += 3 at the bottom it says damage is not referenced, why does this happen?

```
import random, time


inventory = ['dagger','torch']
hp = 50
maxhp = 50
damage = 3
ac = 4
gold = 10
in_combat = False

def choice():
    choose = input(">> ")
    if choose == "stats":
        print("Health:",hp,", Damage:",damage,", Armour: ",ac,", Gold:",gold)
elif choose == "backpack":
    print(inventory)
elif choose == "help":
    print("Keywords:\nstats | view your stats\nbackpack | view your inventory\nhelp | view keywords to input\nattack | attack an enemy when in combat")
else:
    print("Invalid Input")




class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, attack, armour, health):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.armour = armour
        self.health = health

    def attack_enemy(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("What action do you want to make?\nType 'help' for a list of actions\n")
        answer = input(">> ")
        if answer == "attack":
            self.health = self.health - damage
            print(self.name,"health is: ",self.health)



def main():
    while hp > 0:
        if 'dagger' in inventory:
            damage += 3
        print(damage)
        choice()

main()
```

also if I change the code to dagger = 6 at the bottom it will print 6 but when I type stats it will say damage = 3

Comment: `damage` isn't a `global` variable and `main` has its own scope...

Comment: The fix @zondo suggests isn't dealing with the structural problem you have. Why not create another class similar to your Enemy class for the user/player state so it's not cluttering your global namespace? I can put it in an answer if you don't understand what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *read* global variables, but if you wish to assign (rebind) to them, you'll need to tell Python you mean to using the `global` keyword.

In this case there's no need to make those variable global at all.

You should move those attributes into a class. In this example I called it `Player`

```
import random, time


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = ['dagger','torch']
        self.hp = 50
        self.maxhp = 50
        self.damage = 3
        self.ac = 4
        self.gold = 10
        self.in_combat = False

    def choice(self):
        choose = input(">> ")
        if choose == "stats":
            print("Health:", self.hp, ", Damage:", self.damage,
                    ", Armour:", self.ac, ", Gold:", self.gold)
        elif choose == "backpack":
            print(inventory)
        elif choose == "help":
            print("Keywords:\nstats | view your stats\nbackpack | view your inventory\nhelp | view keywords to input\nattack | attack an enemy when in combat")
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")




class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, attack, armour, health):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.armour = armour
        self.health = health

    def attack_enemy(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("What action do you want to make?\nType 'help' for a list of actions\n")
        answer = input(">> ")
        if answer == "attack":
            self.health = self.health - damage
            print(self.name,"health is: ",self.health)



def main():
    pl = Player()
    while pl.hp > 0:
        if 'dagger' in pl.inventory:
            pl.damage += 3
        print(pl.damage)
        pl.choice()

main()
```

Aside: Since you are probably going to be printing lots of multiline blocks, look up the `dedent` function in `textwrap`. You could use it something like this:

```
from textwrap import dedent

def deprint(s):
    print(dedent(s))

...


        elif choose == "help":
            deprint("""
                 Keywords:
                 stats | view your stats
                 backpack | view your inventory
                 help | view keywords to input
                 attack | attack an enemy when in combat""")
```